# "lag"-like function

Tags: c#, sqlite

i have much log-data in an sqlite-database. Every minuten has one row with a primary key which is an datetime-field and a few sensors (all integer).
I display the values as a graph over a time period. If i display all values it would takes ages to display. So i decided to display not all rows of the period but only if the following row is at least a calculated time span later than ne previous. But the descision if the row will be displayed is made after getting the results from sqlite. Is there a posibility to tell sqlite that the following row should have a timestamp at least the calculated period later than the previous (perhaps like "lag()" in oracle sql) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not have window functions.

However, being an embedded database, SQLite runs on the same machine and in the same process as your application, so it does not make much of a difference if a record is read but then rejected by SQLite itself or by your application.

Comment: i thought, sqlite searches only through the index and then reads the entire data for the matching rows!?

Comment: If the search field is indexed, yes. But SQLite reads data in pages, and if the records are small enough so that there are many records in one page (as in your case), and if the matching records aren't localized, SQLite will have to read almost every page anyway.